# Squash/Amend commits without author info

Tags: git, github

I want to squash/amend several commits that don't have any author info (shows Unknown author in github). Though every time I try to interactive rebase or amend, it throws

```
Fatal: empty ident name (for <username@pcName.localdomain>) not allowed
```

Is there any way to get around with that?

Thanks

Comment: In your configuration, are the `user.name` and `user.email` set up?

Comment: When exactly is that message displayed?  When you first start `git rebase -i`, or when it's trying to apply your todo list?

Comment: It happened when it;s trying to apply the list. And the `user.name` and `user.email` are set up and checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git filter-branch --env-filter 'export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=Kirby' keep_this_commit..rewrite_this_branch` ahead of time to make sure all the commits have an author.

Of course, if some of them already have a good author value, you'll need to make the `env-filter` conditional or else put them back with `git commit --amend --author=...` during an `edit` rebase step after the `filter-branch`.